# QGraphicsScene::itemAt() not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to find out the QGraphicsItem under the mouse (when mouse hover over the item). For that I am using `itemAt()` method but `itemAt()` is not returning QGraphicsItem.
I tried this way:

```
bool myViewer::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    bool fEvent = false;
    switch(event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        {....}
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {...}
        case QEvent::Enter:
        {
           QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
           qDebug()<<"Event points = "<< mouseEvent->pos(); // showing points properly
           QPointF po = _view->mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos());       
           
           QGraphicsRectItem* rItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(_scene->itemAt(po,QTransform()));
           if(rItem)
           {
              // some logic
           }
        }
          return true;

       default:
           break;
    }
    return fEvent;
```

I tried with `QGraphicsView::itemAt()` also. But still it did not work.
Note: In both way following lines works fine.

```
 QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
 qDebug()<<"Event points = "<< mouseEvent->pos();
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are using `static_cast` to downcast a `QEvent` to `QMouseEvent`, but at least in the `QEvent::Enter` case, `event` will be pointing to a `QEnterEvent` object, which is not a subclass of `QMouseEvent`, and therefore that `static_cast` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So how should I proceed ? Can you help me ?

Comment: I think you should probably delete the `case QEvent::Enter:` line since a `QEnterEvent` doesn't have any well-defined position, and therefore it doesn't make sense to query the QGraphicsView about a position that you haven't got.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I debugged and found that, `mouseEvent->pos()` is giving wrong points. That's why `itemAt()` is not selecting any `QGraphicsItem`.  Manually I gave correct point to `itemAt()` and I got correct output. Why `mouseEvent->pos()` is not giving correct point ?

Comment: `mouseEvent()->pos()` gives a position in pixels relative to the top-left corner of the `QGraphicsView`.  You'll need to translate that position into the coordinate-system of the `QGraphicsScene` (via `QGraphicsView::mapToScene(QPoint)`) in order to obtain co-ordinate values that are appropriate to pass to the QGraphicsScene's `itemAt()` method.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I did that but still not working. The point is showing `QPointF(449,1562)`   but actual point is  `QPoint(295,77)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try handling `QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress`

And then get the position as said below (pseudo code. Not tetsted.)

```
//Get the scene event object.
QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* sceneEvent = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*>(qevent);

//From the scene event object get the scene position.
QPointF po = sceneEvent->scenePos();
```

Use that position to find the item.

Comment: Sorry but, its not working.

Comment: Just a random try, can you just try with other position functions like  QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::pos()  or QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::screenPos()  or QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::lastScreenPos()   or  sceneEvent->buttonDownScenePos(Qt::LeftButton)